# How to check socket event is fired from my end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am working on a social app and build chat module using socket.io. App is very complicated now and very difficult to debug. sometimes event not received. How I can figure out issue is frontend side or backend side without acknowledgement method because it tells the emitter socket event is listen by client or server. it not handle the case when client can't listen it as user is connected with socket. I confirmed this using server logs.

```
    client.on('webrtc_offer', function (event) {
    console.log("========= webrtc_offer : ", event)
    event.uid = event.endUserId
    event.endUserId = client.uuid
    if (event.uid in users) {
        console.log(`emiting webrtc_offer event to peer  ${event.uid}`)
        client.broadcast.to(users[event.uid]).emit('webrtc_offer_send', event);
        client.emit('ringing', { callee: event.uid, caller_id: event.endUserId })
    }
 })
```

How i can confirmed that "webrtc_offer_send" event is emitted from server or not.? I am not interested it is listen in frontend or not it not my concern.

Comment: When you write "emitted from my end" do you mean "emiitted from my server" ? Or maybe you mean "emitted from my server *and* received by the correct client". Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @O.Jones post updated